# Grouping MYSQL entries using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL table like this example:

```
[ID]--[Date]--[UserID]--[Username]--[String]

1  12-10-06 02:35:01  25  Jack  string1
2  12-10-06 02:38:01  25  Jack  string2
3  12-10-06 02:40:01  25  Jack  END
4  12-10-06 02:42:01  36  Jill  string1
5  12-10-06 02:45:01  36  Jill  string2
6  12-10-06 02:48:01  36  Jill  END
7  12-10-06 02:50:01  25  Jack  string1
8  12-10-06 02:52:01  25  Jack  string2
9  12-10-06 02:55:01  25  Jack  END
```

I'm using this MYSQL query to group them:

```
SELECT m1.Date, m1.Username, m1.UserID
FROM Username m1 LEFT JOIN Username m2
 ON (m1.UserID = m2.UserID AND m1.ID < m2.ID)
WHERE m2.ID IS NULL
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

It works but the problem with this query is that it only gives the last entry of each user as the output:

```
6  12-10-06 02:48:01  36  Jill
9  12-10-06 02:55:01  25  Jack
```

I want to get all sessions as the output, like:

```
12-10-06 02:35:01 - 12-10-06 02:40:01 25 Jack
12-10-06 02:42:01 - 12-10-06 02:48:01 25 Jill
12-10-06 02:50:01 - 12-10-06 02:55:01 25 Jack
```

How can I accomplish this with PHP and MYSQL?

Comment: Seems complex. I don't think you need to use `LEFT JOIN` for this.

Comment: Is 'END' really the value of the string? or it's something you just placed there to clarify your point?

Comment: The real value is 'cikis' but yes, I have placed there to clarify it's an ending string.

Comment: I just tried a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48452/3).

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48452/15 This query gives what I want but it hangs my MYSQL server as there are over 10000+ entries. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I doubt you ever want to query the entire database for sessions, so for the chunk you want, I think I would just fetch the end, and then for each one of them request a different.

Do something like this

```
select UserID, Date, Username from Username order by Date desc limit 10
```

And then for each one of those entries you can do

Get when the last session from the user ended:

```
select max(Date) from Username where UserID = $userId and Date < '$date' and String = 'cikis'
```

Get the min date between those 2 dates:

```
select min(Date) from Username where Date > '$lastSessionEndDate' and Date < '$date'
```

It shouldn't hammer the database too much, just build appropriate indexes and limit your queries to what it's really useful rather than just presenting a full report on all sessions for no reason.